# How do I read a CAPTCHA with Java?

Tags: java, captcha

I always hear that reading a CAPTCHA is impossible and so now I want to write an open source CAPTCHA reader in Java. Was wondering what I should be looking for... any good books? Any ideas on where to start?

I know this is a bit over my head, but I am still going to at least try.

Comment: The whole point of Captcha is to prevent this from happening. What legitimate purpose could this serve?

Comment: @jny Computer visualization is a field with enormous potential.  Certainly there is _some_ possible benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at JDownloader. Part of their code reads captchas.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any Java code on how to do this, but I do remember reading [this paper](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/kumarc/pubs/chellapilla_nips04.pdf) on how to break some of the older Captcha variants.  I don't know how applicable this is in modern Captchas, but some of the techniques here might be useful.  Be warned - this is a pretty technical paper.

Also, you should probably be aware that the best known techniques for breaking Captchas these days are [to give them to humans in exchange for some reward](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/btl/this-stripper-is-paid-in-captchas/6800).